# How to add a string to all integer value of dictionary

Tags: python

I have made a dictionary that with following code. I want to add a string "English" to all values but since there is integer in the value it does not accept.

```
key = ["I", "you", "we", "us", "they", "their"]

value = list(range(len(key)))

dictionary = dict(zip(key,value))

print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'they': 4, 'I': 0, 'you': 1, 'we': 2, 'us': 3, 'their': 5}
```

I want following output:

```
output = {'they': 'English 4', 'I': 'English 0', 'you': 'English 1', 'we': 'English 2', 'us': 'English 3', 'their': 'English 5'}
```

Comment: The values you list aren't legal Python.  Do you want a a string "English 0", or a tuple ("English", 0), or something else?

Comment: ^ Suggested edit. @Prune

Comment: I want to get tuple

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension. change

```
value = range(len(key))
dictionary = dict(zip(key, ['English {}'.format(i) for i in value]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean having 2 different fields for every value (one is index, one is language). To do that you just turn `value` into a list of tuples instead lf a single value.

So `value` should contain `((0, "English"), (1, "English"), ... (len(key), "English"))`

You can do  that easily with `enumerate`:

`value = enumerate(["English"] * len(key))`

Output:

```
{'their': (5, 'English'), 'you': (1, 'English'), 'us': (3, 'English'), 'I': (0, 'English'), 'they': (4, 'English'), 'we': (2, 'English')}
```

(iyou might have realized: `enumerate(a)` returns every item of `a` with index attached, i.e. `( (0, a[0]), (1, a[1]) , (2, a[2]), ...)`